# $0 \in $ CI, should we consider p-value? If so, how?

Tags: statistics, regression, hypothesis-testing

Here is the summary of my linear model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ height, data = height and weight)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-10.267  -4.267  -1.267   6.455  11.538 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)       20.4878     5.8335   3.512  0.00158 **
height             0.3195     0.1447   2.208  0.03596 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.703 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1529,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1215 
F-statistic: 4.873 on 1 and 27 DF,  p-value: 0.03596
```

And here is my confidence interval for $\hat{\beta}_1$: `0.02260012 0.61639988` at $5\%$ level.

As you can see $0 \notin $CI at $5\%$ level. Also, the $p$-value for the test $H_0: \beta_1=0$ turns out to be $0.03596 $ which is in between $0.01 <0.03596 < 0.05$.

> How do I interpret this?

The p-value < 0.05 should mean that there is moderate evidence against the null hypothesis $H_0: \beta_1=0$, also, $0$ is not in CI. So should I reject the fact that $\beta_1=0$ or should I say the evidence is not strong enough?

Furthermore, what would happen if in the same situation, I would get $0 \in CI$ but still $p-$value <0.05?

What about $p-$value >0.05 but $0\in CI$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Interpretation: The probability of making a mistake in rejecting $H_0$ is $0.03596$.

2) Your hypothetical scenarios are impossible as for confidence level of $95\%$, p.value$<0.05$ iff $0 \notin CI $.

Let $T$ be a random variable that follows the Student's $T$ distribution with $n$ df, then by definition, 
$$
p.v = P(T> |T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})|) = 1- P(T\le |T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})|), 
$$
i.e.,
$$
1-p.v = P(T\le |T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})|) = P( - |T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})| \le T\le |T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})|). 
$$
Thus, $(1-p.v)100\%$ CI of the studentized $\beta$ is
$$
( -| T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})| , |T_{stat}(\hat{\beta})|).
$$

Comment: thank you! Is there a way we can prove this?

Comment: I've edited the answer